# Magnific Pop-up double load from external link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, magnific-popup

We have implemented magnific pop-up to our [website](http://www.spottedbylocals.com) for internal links only. When a user clicks from an external link (i.e. Facebook, Google) we would like to load it without the pop-up. In fact there is a second template besides the one with the magnific pop-up for the same content (article) especially for this (external links). However when a user clicks an external link (direct link to the content) it first loads the content without the pop-up and on top of that it loads again the content with the pop-up. How can we eliminate the on top second loading for external links?
Example [page](http://www.spottedbylocals.com/amsterdam/canvas/)